# match elements from two files, how to write the intended format to a new file

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to update my text file by matching the first column to another updated file's first column, after match it, it will update the old file.
Here is my `oldfile`:

```
Name Chr Pos ind1 in2 in3 ind4
foot 1 5 aa bb cc
ford 3 9 bb cc 00
fake 3 13 dd ee ff
fool 1 5 ee ff gg
fork 1 3 ff gg ee
```

Here is the `newfile`:

```
Name Chr Pos
foot 1 5
fool 2 5
fork 2 6
ford 3 9
fake 3 13
```

The updated file will be like:

```
Name Chr Pos ind1 in2 in3 ind4
foot 1 5 aa bb cc
fool 2 5 ee ff gg
fork 2 6 ff gg ee
ford 3 9 bb cc 00
fake 3 13 dd ee ff
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
inputfile_1 = sys.argv[1]
inputfile_2 = sys.argv[2]
outputfile = sys.argv[3]

inputfile1 = open(inputfile_1, 'r')
inputfile2 = open(inputfile_2, 'r')
outputfile = open(outputfile, 'w')

ind = inputfile1.readlines()
cm = inputfile2.readlines()[1:]

outputfile.write(ind[0]) #add header

for i in ind:        
    i = i.split()
    for j in cm:
        j = j.split()
        if j[0] == i[0]:
            outputfile.writelines(j[0:3] + i[3:])
            outputfile.write('\n')
inputfile1.close()
inputfile2.close()
outputfile.close()
```

When I ran it, `./compare_substitute_2files.py oldfile newfile output`
the values were updated for the file, but they did not follow the order of the new file, and no space was there as indicated in the output below.

```
Name Chr Pos ind1 in2 in3 ind4
foot15aabbcc
ford39bbcc00
fake313ddeeff
fool25eeffgg
fork26ffggee
```

My question is how to match to the exact order and give spaces to each element in the list when write them out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`file.write`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write) accepts `string` as its parameter.

If you want write sequences of strings instead of string, use [`file.writelines`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.writelines) method instead:

```
outputfile.writelines(j[0:2] + i[3:])
```

Comment: Thank you, this indeed got rid of error, but the output was odd:Name Chr Pos ind1 in2 in3 ind4
foot1aabbccford3bbcc00fake3ddeefffool2eeffggfork2ffggee

Comment: @user2489612, If you want each items are separated by newline, explicitly join them: `outputfile.writelines('\n'.join(j[0:2] + i[3:])); outputfile.write('\n')`